# Can PAM module authenticates users against Django login credentials?

Tags: django, authentication, pam, vsftpd

I have a Django web application running on Server1 with around 9000 users. Now i would like to create a vsftpd server on Server2 and enable all the 9000 users to access their own home folders using credentials of web-app on Server1.

I want to have a PAM authentication on server2 where users are validated against webapp on server1. If a user is deleted or updated his password on server1, FTP access has to be allowed/denied accordingly. i.e User Authentication server has to be my webapp only.

Is django logins by default SSO compliant? Can i have LDAP server inside Django with the same users&passwords?